# Java не видит каталог и содержимое "/usr/local/"

Tags: java, linux-mint

Всем привет!

```
new File("/usr/local/").exists();
```

result = false

Хотя файл существует.

```
roma@roma-HP:/usr$ ls -l 
итого 148
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 69632 окт  5 16:00 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 июн 24 21:33 games
drwxr-xr-x  46 root root 20480 окт  2 17:01 include
drwxr-xr-x 125 root root  4096 окт  5 16:00 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root  4096 окт  1 18:33 lib64
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root 12288 окт  2 17:02 libexec
drwxr-xr-x  11 root root  4096 окт  5 17:28 local
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 12288 окт  2 17:02 sbin
drwxr-xr-x 322 root root 12288 окт  5 16:00 share
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root  4096 окт  2 17:02 src
```

Часть файлов из данного каталога видит, часть нет.
к примеру bin lib include видит
а src local games нет

ОС Linux mint 20

Comment: Попробуйте запустить программу от имени администратора.

Comment: если запускаю через Idea false, через командную строку (без sudo ) true.

Comment: Но мне важно чтобы проект запускался через Idea правильно работало .

Answer (score 0):

Я установил Idea через встроенный менеджер приложений, на сайте JB написано, что тогда она не будит видеть некоторые директории.